# Angular 4.2.4 animations with params don't work

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have the following animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('moveSomething', [
        state('true', style({left: '{{leftPosition}}' , opacity: 0.5}), {params: {leftPosition: 0}}),
        transition('* => *', animate(300))
    ])
]
```

And this is the html

```
[@moveSomething]="{value: shouldMove, leftPosition: leftPosition}"
```

I know for sure the animation is triggered because I see the opacity changing. I read a bunch of documentation and answers on stack overflow and can't seem to see the problem.

I want to mention that the `leftPosition` is an integer, but I also tried with a variable that was string that was in this form `150px`, but without success.

Any thoughts of why this isn't working?

Comment: Does the element have `position: absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`? Otherwise the `left` property may not do anything.

Comment: Yes, this works if instead of the parameter I use `{left: '50px'}`

Comment: Is it possible that the third point from the 4.2.6 release to fix this? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#426-2017-07-08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I thought that I had Angular 4.2.4, but instead it was 4.4.7 and I was trying to send the parameters the way they were sent before 4.4.6.

The final solution was

```
animations: [
    trigger('moveSomething', [
        state('true', style({left: '{{leftPosition}}px' , opacity: 0.5}), {params: {leftPosition: 0}}),
        transition('* => *', animate(300))
    ])
]
```

And the HTML

```
[@moveSomething]="{value: shouldMove, params: {leftPosition: leftPosition}}"
```